# How to break out of a LONG infinite loop

Tags: android, loops, exit, break, infinite

I searched but didn't find a solution.
I have an infinite game loop running in a thread. It is very very long, so when I exit my app and use while(condition), it will keep going on respectively start another application in Android.
How can I stop it?
Must I check between EVERY method, if the thread got an interrupted-signal?

Comment: I am really interested on an answer for this question, but for a short infinite loop.

Comment: At the exit point, put System.exit(0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your loop run on another thread, you could create your own custom thread extending with. Simple add a stop method to it and you are done.

the idea:

```
private boolean run = true;

public class MyThread extends Thread{

    public void stopThread(){
        run = false;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run(){
        while(run){
            //large code block
            if(!run)break; //to make sure the thread will stop in time
            //another large code block
        }
    }
}
```

simply call myThread.stopThread() to stop it almost immediately.

You could also use a ASyncTask, which has a method cancel(boolean) to stop it immediately.

Comment: but if i have multiple threads running, i have a thread starting another anonymous thread, how can i stop all of them together?

Comment: same answere, because that doesn't matter

Comment: This was related to the Thread.stop() e.g. in onPause(), but if i use this run flag, i could solve it this way too, but if i only want to shut the activity down, doesn't matter if some information get lost. btw i read that asynctask should be used only for short periods and not like this gameloop in a thread?

Comment: a service for a gameloop, sounds very strange oO